# Comparison of set of signals

Tags: matlab, comparison, signals, shapes, similarity

I have certain movement data acquired from motion capture system which I want to automatically choose which 5 signals are more alike. 
Picture shows example of the particular data, all normalized to 100 samples due to the difference in speed.

[Data set for knee flexion/extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6kjM.png)

What I am looking for is some idea to actually compare the shapes of the curves.

Comment: This question is not a programming question because you don't know which similarity metric to chose. It is a math/statistics question. I recommend to take a look at stats.stackexchange.com and look for similar questions, I am sure it is already discussed there. If you don't find anything create a new question. Once you have chosen a metric to measure the difference, I assume you will find it already implemented in matlab. If you have any issues implementing it, feel free to ask here a question about your programming issue.[Some introduction in the matlab documentation](http://goo.gl/Oh8ZLo)

Comment: Perhaps use a cross correlation algorithm to determine the error between the curves, and keep those with the least error between them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is just to substract the "raw" curves and check which one has the smallest `RMSE`.

But looking at your data (which are smooth curves), another option is to use `PLS` or `GMM` to describe them. Then you can use `RMSE` to compute the error between your input curve and your database of curves and take the one with lowest error.